# Haskell; How to change int to a specific string?

Tags: haskell, integer

In Haskell how am I able to convert the `Int` value `4496`, into the `String` value `4.496m`. As to represent 4.496 million?

Comment: What did you try? What is not working?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Take a look at how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the scope of the question but here is one way...

```
Prelude> toMil x = show (x/1000)  ++ "m"
Prelude> toMil 4496
"4.496m"
```

Comment: [FIXED]

Hi after tweaking what you said I managed to get it to work with 
```hs
toMill :: Int -> String
toMill x = show ( fromIntegral x / 1000)  ++ "m"
```
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative answer, using `x/1000`, has some fun behaviors that may or may not be what you want. For example:

```
> 0/1000
0.0 -- not 0.000
> 1/1000
1.0e-3 -- scientific notation
> (2^53)/1000 == (2^53+1)/1000
True -- imprecise
```

There may be examples where rounding will bite you as well, causing some output like `A.BCD9999999` or something, though I'm not sure how to construct one quickly. An alternative that has a predictable format is to use the built-in `Fixed` family of types for fixed point arithmetic; the [`Milli`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html#t:Milli) type in particular being relevant. The above examples print like this:

```
> 0/1000 :: Milli
0.000
> 1/1000 :: Milli
0.001
> (2^53)/1000 == ((2^53+1) / 1000 :: Milli)
False
```

Here's a complete code snippet showing how to use it:

```
import Data.Fixed

toMil :: Int -> String
toMil x = show (MkFixed (toInteger x) :: Milli) ++ "m"
```

In fact, you might just want to start from having a `Milli` lying around in the first place rather than an `Int` -- it will give you all sorts of nice things, like multiplication behaving in the way you expect:

```
> 1000 * 1000 :: Int
1000000
> let MkFixed n = MkFixed 1000 * (MkFixed 1000 :: Milli) in n
1000
```

That is, 1000 milli-things is 1 thing, and 1*1 thing = 1 thing = 1000 milli-things, not 1000000 milli-things.